# How I check the color is match or not? (memory game with match color)

Tags: java, swing, awt, graph-drawing

I got 2 array,for color and button

```
private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[16];
private Color[] c={
    Color.red,Color.yellow,Color.black,Color.magenta,
    Color.blue,Color.green,Color.cyan,Color.pink,
    Color.green,Color.black,Color.red,Color.pink,
    Color.magenta,Color.blue,Color.cyan,Color.yellow
};
```

and the Layout is

```
DrawingPanel c=new DrawingPanel();
c.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
```

when I clicked 2 button,the 2 button will be remove, then how can I check the 2 color(the color is on button back) is match or not?

```
public class bl implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Component c = (Component)e.getSource();
        Color c1=Color.black,c2=Color.black;
        if(clickCount == 2){
            c.hide();
            c1 = c.getBackground();
            clickCount--;
        }if(clickCount ==1){
            c.hide();
            c2 = c.getBackground();
            clickCount--;
        }
        if(clickCount == 0 ){
            if(bx == by){
                System.out.println("Corret");
                clickCount=2;
            }
        }else{
            c.show();
        }
    }
}
```

[Full code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wfaLmFm5Xm9bK214js3vfiedxsNKQViI/view)

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: What are you trying to do with the code?

Comment: A memory game with match color

Comment: Please post more code.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wfaLmFm5Xm9bK214js3vfiedxsNKQViI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please, edit the question, by adding the code in the google drive link so its available at a single glance.

Comment: Do a simple test `System.out.println(Color.yellow.equals(Color.green));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend the Button class to be able to hold a record of its colour and then get it each time to compare.

The button needs to keep a record of what colour it has, or something has to anyway.

General advice bro: 
1. Give your variables meaningful names:

```
    DrawingPanel c=new DrawingPanel();        
    c.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
```

This is way better and makes your code far easier to read:

```
    DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
    drawingPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
```

2. It never hurts to add descriptive comments everywhere as well, makes code far easier to read.

To extend Button you could go something like this:

```
    public class ColourButton extends JButton{

    private final String colourOfButton;

    public ColourButton(String colourOfButton){

    this.colourOfButton = colourOfButton;
    }

    public String getColour(){
     return colourOfButton;            
     }

      }
```

Then use something like this to check for colour matches:

```
     public boolean hasColourMatch(ColourButton colourButton1, ColourButton colourButton2){
          if(colourButton1.getColour().equals(colourButton2.getColour())){
            return true;         
           }
            return false;
      }
```

Hope this helps..